# Is there a way to get "this.lastID" from sqlite.run() callback using es6 and react classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sqlite, ecmascript-6

I would like to get the "last insert id" from inside the callback of the `sqlite.run('INSERT INTO table...', {}, callback)` function. The docs say, it is possible using `this.lastID` inside the callback function.

In my project I use react and node.js (electron) with es6 classes. So my callback function is a arrow function, that (according to the docs from mdn) doesn't get its own `this`, it uses `this` of the surrounding code (in this case my react class):

```
this.db.run(
    'INSERT INTO table...',
    {},
    (error) => {
        // check error
        if(error !== null) {
            this.props.addNotification({
                open: true,
                variant: 'error',
                message: error.message,
                autoClose: null,
            });
        } else {
            this.props.route.history.push('/...');
            this.props.closeForm();
        }
    }
);
```

I tried to switch to classic declaration of the callback function, with the following result:

```
function(error) {
    ...
    console.log(this.lastID); // is available
    this.props.route.history.push('...'); // cannot access property route of undefined
}
```

Both behaviour is understandable, but is there a way to get both `this.lastID` from callback function and access to `this.props` or `this.state` from react class?

Comment: `var component = this; // outer scope` and then `component.props.route // inside callback`

Comment: Or go fancy `(cb => function(error) {return cb(error, this.lastId)})((error, lastId) => {})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously you can't have two different `this` value.

The simplest solution would be to capture the outer context in a closure

```
const component = this

this.db.run(
    'INSERT INTO table...',
    {},
    function (error) {
        console.log(this.lastId) // is available
        // check error
        if(error !== null) {
            component.props.addNotification({
                open: true,
                variant: 'error',
                message: error.message,
                autoClose: null,
            });
        } else {
            component.props.route.history.push('/...');
            component.props.closeForm();
        }
    }
);
```

or you could create a temp normal function that would pass `this.lastId` to your callback as the second argument

```
this.db.run(
    'INSERT INTO table...',
    {},
    (cb => function(){return cb(error, this.lastId)})((error, lastId) => {
        console.log(lastId) // is available
        // check error
        if(error !== null) {
            this.props.addNotification({
                open: true,
                variant: 'error',
                message: error.message,
                autoClose: null,
            });
        } else {
            this.props.route.history.push('/...');
            this.props.closeForm();
        }
    })
)
```

Comment: I'll give that "fancy" solution a try, that keeps me `this` being the react object `this` in my current function body...

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

```
// above function
const self= this;
// inside function
function(error) {
  this.lastId;
  self.props.history;
  self.state;
}
```